# Why is the function continuous at a point which gives the case 0/0?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have this function : $f(x) = \frac{6x^2+18x+12}{x^2-4}$, the domain is R. How come its graph is continuous at $x = -2$? I know it can be simplified to $\frac{6(x+1)}{x-2}$ ( firstly $f(x) = \frac{6(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$ ). But for this simplification $x$ must not be $-2$ or $+2$.

If I plot the function using different sites on the internet $f$ is continuous at $x = -2$. Why is that true? If $x = -2$ it is the $0/0$ case, even if for the simplification it's not. The simplification implies that $x$ is not $-2$.

http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoNip4XjIrMTh4KzEyKS8oeF4yLTQpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTI2IiwiMjYiLCItMTYiLCIxNiJdfV0-

Comment: The domain is not $\Bbb R$; the function isn't defined at $2$ nor at $-2$.

Comment: How do you know that it is continuous looking at the plot?

Comment: It should show a plot hole, or not? Not sure

Comment: http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoNip4XjIrMTh4KzEyKS8oeF4yLTQpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDAwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTI2IiwiMjYiLCItMTYiLCIxNiJdfV0-

Comment: I can see where the confusion lies.. Wolfram gives [this plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%29+%3D+%286x^2%2B18x%2B12%29%2F%28x^2%E2%88%924%29) which is continuous at $x = -2$

Comment: That means the plot is wrong? The function cannot be continuous at that point

Comment: You have observed that the function has a removable singularity at $x=-2$. That is, the function $f$ can be extended to a function $f^*$ which is continuous at $x=-2$ by defining $f^*(-2)=\frac32$.

Comment: That's right. My confusion lies in the fact that on that plot it shows that the UNextended function is continuous at x = -2. Do these online softwares automatically find removable discontinuities and complete them ?

Answer (score 1):

The function is not *defined* at the point $-2$, but it can be *extended* continuously at this point. As you have seen for $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{2,-2\}$ you have

$$f(x)=6\frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}=6\frac{x+1}{x-2}$$

Now as $x\to-2$ the expression will *always* approach $6\frac{-1}{4}=-3/2$. This means that the function $g: \mathbb{R}-\{2\} \to \mathbb R$, $$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & x \neq -2\\ -3/2 & x=-2\end{cases}$$

is continuous, and if you restrict it to the domain of $f$ you will get $f$.

$$g\lvert_{\mathbb R -\{2,-2\}} = f$$

This is then example of the concept of the continuous continuation of a function to a larger domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler example with the same features.

Define the function $g: (-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ by $$g(x)=\frac{x}{x}$$
 This is *not* continuous at $0$, because it is not even defined at $0$. But obviously it can be simplified to $g(x)=1$ on its domain, where $x$ is non-zero. So the function $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$h(x)=1$$

is an extension of $g$ to the whole of $\mathbb R$, that is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but in the end they are different functions, right? Why the plot of g shows that it is continuous at x = 0 if I use different softwares?

Comment: The plot does have a gap at $x=0$, but unfortunately this gap has zero width...